# Javascript precision mitigation

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, orbital-mechanics

[image]

I understand that the javascript rounding errors are fairly intractable, but I would like some advice.

What would be the best way to mitigate the rounding errors for my application? I have a cube in what SHOULD be an orbit around a large mass. The cube gains a significant amount of orbital momentum every orbit, and will eventually reach escape velocity without any intervention.

I need a lightweight method to prevent this happening.

Is my best bet to try and find a way to fix my numbers, or would I be better off using error correction based on a logical assumption of where it should be to sort of fudge it and put it back where it belongs?

The functions for my physics are here:

```
function physPosition(object, delta){
// Update Position
object.position.x += (object.velocity.x * delta) + (0.5*object.acceleration.x*   (Math.pow(delta,2)));
object.position.y += (object.velocity.y * delta) + (0.5*object.acceleration.y*(Math.pow(delta,2)));
object.position.z += (object.velocity.z * delta) + (0.5*object.acceleration.z*(Math.pow(delta,2)));

// Update Velocity (acceleration)
object.velocity.x += object.acceleration.x * delta;
object.velocity.y += object.acceleration.y * delta;
object.velocity.z += object.acceleration.z * delta;

// Update Velocity (gravity)
object.velocity.x += object.gravity.x * delta;
object.velocity.y += object.gravity.y * delta;
object.velocity.z += object.gravity.z * delta;

// Update Rotation
object.rotation.x += object.spin.x * delta; 
object.rotation.y += object.spin.y * delta; 
object.rotation.z += object.spin.z * delta; 
}
```

`function physGravity(a, b){
    var grav = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    grav = grav.subVectors(a.position, b.position);
    var r = grav.lengthSq();
    var A = (G)*(b.mass)/(r);
    grav = grav.normalize();
    grav.multiplyScalar(-A);
    a.gravity = grav;
}`

Comment: The best way of dealing with accumulated errors imo are describing the path with mathematical equations instead computing new values over and over.

Comment: Can't remember my math. Can you post the relevant formulas? If you had a parametric formula, as Derek suggests, you wouldn't be having this problem, so I assume you have some `dx` and `dy` incremental calculation?

Comment: I added the relevant code. It also calculates gravitational attraction every physics frame.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do a numerical integration of the equations of motion. This is one valid solution - another one would be to compute the analytical solution of the equations of motion, as suggested by Derek. The thing is, you need a better integrator than the solution you are using now. You should try to learn about [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). In particular, I would recommend [Runge-Kutta methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), as they are easy to implement and to use.

You could also find a JavaScript library that contains numerical integration methods, and use those rather than implementing your own. There is an example [here](http://mtdevans.com/2013/05/fourth-order-runge-kutta-algorithm-in-javascript-with-demo/) with a fourth-order Runge-Kutta method, and the [Numeric JavaScript library](http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html) contains a Dormand-Prince integrator called `dopri`.

Answer (score 0):

While Derek's comment makes sense - make all functions parametric if you can rather than differential - sometimes you can't really do that, or not easily. With your code, another possibility (not sure how realistic) is to try to keep the error down using fractions yourself, instead of relying on floating point arithmetic, since you don't have any formulae that are inimical to fractions (like square roots).

Implement your own fraction arithmetic, always keeping numerator and denominator separate, and dividing only when you absolutely need to in order to calculate the point's coordinates. This should: increase the precision, since you have double the available number of bits; also, the floating point error comes mostly from things not being representable in base 2, but you'd have things as much as integers as JavaScript would allow. You might need to normalize the numerator and denominator from time to time as they threaten to get out of range, which will reintroduce some error, but less frequently than at each division as you are doing with plain floating point arithmetic.

Obviously, it will also slow you down a smidgen, but JavaScript is quite fast on calculation.

Comment: I'm actually doing gravity calculations each frame:
`function physGravity(a, b){  
 var grav = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);  
 grav = grav.subVectors(a.position, b.position);  
 var r = grav.lengthSq();  
 var A = (G)*(b.mass)/(r);  
 grav = grav.normalize();  
 grav.multiplyScalar(-A);  
 a.gravity = grav;  
}`

The code needs to be able to handle any object I put anywhere, so making specific parametrics would require making some sort of heuristic linear regression. That sounds like a fun challenge, and I might try it later.